# How to replace printStackTrace with log.error in the below method

Tags: javascript, java, log4j, log4j2, printstacktrace

Please suggest me how to replace the printstacktace lines with log.error

```
public class extends Throwable {
    
    private Throwable _prev;

    public synchronized Throwable getPrevThrowable() {
       return _prev;
    }
    
    public void printStackTrace(PrintStream ps) {
       super.printStackTrace(ps);
       Throwable t;
       if ((t = getPrevThrowable()) != null) {
           t.printStackTrace(ps);
       }
            }
```

Can I implement it like below ??

```
public class extends Throwable {
        
            public void printStackTrace(PrintStream ps) {
                log.error(ps);
                Throwable t;
                if ((t = getPrevThrowable()) != null) {
                    log.error(t);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Simply pass the exception to your logger. The logging framework you're using should provide documentation about this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what getPrevThrowable() does but you can do

```
Throwable t;
if ((t = getPrevThrowable()) != null {
    logger.error("", t);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, what about the line super.printStackTrace()   ?

Comment: What about it? First, it is impossible to tell what super.printStackTrace() does because you haven't identified what class this is or what it extends. 

You asked how to replace the printStackTrace lines with logging to error. That is what it does without knowing anything else.

If we are to assume that this is a Throwable (which is a stretch since getPrevThrowable() is not a method of Throwable) then you would use logger.error("", this). But if the previous Throwable is chained to the current Throwable there is no need to log it separately.